# Set minimum patch version

Tags: npm, semantic-versioning

Using semver as the standard, so I have this package version:

```
0.0.108
```

so in package.json for a Node.js project, I might have something like:

```
"foo":"^0.0.108"
```

my question is - using semver notation, how can I tell NPM not to install anything below 0.0.108? For example, `0.0.107` is unacceptable, but `0.0.109`, or `0.0.111` is ok?

Comment: `^0.0.108` *is* how you tell NPM not to install anything below 0.0.108. If you want the patch to be allowed to change, then it'd be `~` rather than `^`, as `108` is the *"leftmost non-zero digit"*. See the explanations in https://www.npmjs.com/package/semver and the examples in https://semver.npmjs.com/

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want anything in `0.1.x`, then this should work

```
>=0.0.108 <0.1
```

If you are okay with any future versions, such as major releases, then you only need

```
>=0.0.108
```

Note the [semver spec](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver) (Section 4) and the [npm documentation on semver](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver) (Caret Ranges) both suggest there can be breaking changes for every release when the minor version number is still `0`, so you may have to deal with those if you decide not to use `^0.0.108`.